# Differences between Darkest Dungeon on PC vs Nintendo Switch

Tags: pc, version-differences, nintendo-switch, darkest-dungeon

What are the significant differences between Darkest Dungeon's PC version and switch version?

Differences considered significant:

- Game mechanic differences
- Addition/removal of game content
- Addition/removal of game lore

Differences NOT considered significant are those that are done to support the new console, such as:

- Resolutions supported
- UI for settings
- Controls supported

Comment: What counts as a significant difference?

Comment: @Frank Edited to clarify.

Comment: Are there reasons to think that there are significant differences? Most cross-platform ports don't typically do things like this.

Comment: @ChrisHayes this does happen a lot with games that are ported much later than their original release. They might add new content, pack DLC (even DLC that has become unavailable since) or even remaster the game. For example, many Final Fantasy or Dragon Quest games have significant differences between versions, most notably when games were ported from consoles to handhelds, or vice versa. Of course, as you say, most commonly ports don't differ very much from their originals.

Answer (score 6):

I've played both of them, and I've noticed no significant differences.

The closest that I've seen is that the control scheme is slightly different (as it has to be, going from keyboard/mouse to joycons), but no functionality is actually removed or inaccessible.